# Me.Close on Windows 7/2008

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm in the process of writing a VB app that launches at user login. The issue I see is that on Windows 7/2008 when closing the last form using both Me.Close or Application.Exit both throw the error message "did the application close properly". On WindowsXP it closes without issue.

One of the basic features of the app is that when loading it checks some values and closes the app based on those values. Even in this instance I get the "did not close properly" message on win 7/2008. What could I be doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Dialog1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If fName = failsafeUser Then
        allowLogin = vbTrue
        Process.Start(My.Settings.ExplorerPath)
        'Me.Close() ' TODO Check into why Me.Close() is ending poorly on 2008 servers
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
End
```

to close your app.  That should work.  Obviously application.Exit is the better option, but End should work.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: WOW. I am floored that Me.Close or Application.Exit both cause this error in win7/2008 but using just End simply works. Thanks for the assist Paul.